# CloudFormation error - creation failed as requested capacity is not available in the specified availability zone

Tags: templates, aws-cloudformation

I am facing an issue in the CloudFormation template. It fails sometimes (not always) with the error message -

":resource_status_reason: Your requested instance type (c3.large) is not supported
    in your requested Availability Zone (us-east-1a). Please retry your request by
    not specifying an Availability Zone or choosing us-east-1b, us-east-1d, us-east-1c,
    us-east-1e."

I tried by not specifying the AZ explicitly and let the CloudFormation decide it at runtime but I still getting the error frequently with the same error message for different AZ's. Is there any way to check the resource availability in advance for the availability zone and force the resource to launch in the zone where the capacity available withing CloudFormation template?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Region and Availability Zone (AZ) are not the same thing, to be perfectly clear. Your region is us-east-1, your AZ is one of us-east-1a, us-east-1b, etc, etc.

To answer your question, there is not a clear way to determine availability from CloudFormation itself - your best bet is to assign your EC2 to launch specifically in one of the supported regions using the AvailabilityZone property.

Comment: Ok, so what if I need to launch 10 instances in the same Subnet by CloudFormation only? Is there is no way to avoid this capacity problem? My thinking is AWS should pick the well capacity AZ if it is not explicitly specified. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It's not a capacity problem, your chosen AZ simply doesn't support launching any instances of the c3.large type.

Comment: I don't think so because the failure is not consistent in us-east-1a AZ. My CloudFormation stack sometimes gets launch successfully in us-east-1a AZ.

Comment: Are they always c3 instance types? That is what the error is saying.

Comment: I initially got this with m3.large instance types, and I changed the instance types to c3.large to use fewer resources and hopefully avoid the availability problem, but it's showing up again causing the cloud formations to fail periodically.